# simulating nmcli --ask in direct dbus control of networkmanager

Tags: java, dbus, networkmanager

I'm going through a Java software product and replacing `exec()` calls to *nmcli* with more direct control of NetworkManager via dbus.  I've got stuck on `nmcli connection up (ourconnection) --ask`;  specifically, the `--ask` bit of it.

I understand that it will be a call to *ActivateConnection* as described in the [NetworkManager documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.ActivateConnection) but can't see how to emulate `--ask`.  When you specify `--ask`, is it an option which NetworkManager takes and enacts, or is `nmcli` that asks for the password before passing it to NetworkManager?

This question is specifically about `--ask`;  I understand in general how to interact with NetworkManager via dbus using Java classes obtained from the reflection API calls, and have been doing so to obtain lists of SSIDs, devices and connections, as well as setting-up handlers for signals such as *AccessPointAdded*;  but I don't see how to tell NetworkManager, programmatically, to prompt the human user for a password.

Comment: Try using Bustle (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bustle/bustle) to capture the D-Bus traffic when you use `nmcli --ask` vs without `--ask` and see what differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other reasons, I had to dig into the [source code](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager) of `nmcli` and found that the password is being requested by `nmcli` and passed over dbus.